# Get reference out of a function from a Option<Rc<RefCell>>> borrow() OR a value not wrapped in a RefCell

Tags: rust

I have nodes with optional parents. If I can't find `Stuff` locally, I'll consult the parent, if any. Parents never change. (I know that, but rust doesn't)
So, I created this recursive function:

```
//impl Node {...
pub fn get_stuff(&self, id: &str) -> Option<Ref<Stuff>> {
       if self.stuff_map.contains_key(id) { //stuff_map: HashMap<String, Stuff>
           self.stuff_map.get(id) //How do I turn this into a Ref<>?
       } else {
           if self.parent.is_some() { // parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>
                //as suggested, I'm using Ref::map():
                Ref::map(self.parent.as_ref().unwrap().borrow(), |node| node.get_stuff(id)) 
                //Given the new function signature, this creates a Ref<Ref<...>>, so that doesn't work.
           } else {
               None
           }
      }
}
```

The problem with this recursive function is that local `Stuff` is...well, just unwrapped `Stuff`, but the parent's `Stuff` is wrapped in a `RefCell`.
The suggested solution with a Ref::map() doesn't resolve the problem.
With that solution, every deeper call to this function, will wrap another `Ref<...>` to the data.
Drewtato suggests cloning the `Rc`, but I don't see how the lack of a `RefCell` for the `self` level will be solved this way.

Maybe I need another approach. The ultimate question is : How do I create a tree structure that allows me to recurse upward and return a reference to data somewhere in the tree?

Comment: On second thought, since your function is recursive, this is a bit different. You do need to return `Ref` but you'll also need to deal with the fact that the top level isn't inside a `RefCell` and you'll need to clone the inner `Rc`s.

Comment: I'd like to re-open this question to answer with an alternative, namely, instead of getting a ref out of a complex structure like a tree or graph, bring the thing you want to do inside the structure, with a closure or something. I actually got it to work this way, and it's likely more idiomatic, and functionally, you avoid the need for reference that needs lifetime tracking. It's the idea behind the visitor pattern, I believe.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed a workable solution. It's used in `std::thread::scope` for somewhat different reasons but with the same effect.

Comment: Coincidently, the actual node struct in my project is also called `Scope`.
My Find-One-Node-And-Visit contraption takes a closure that returns a generic result, making it surprisingly flexible, as rust simply infers the return type. I'm learning a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The tree structure is fine. An alternative approach to access the data is indeed better: **the visitor pattern**, or rather, a variation of it. The general idea of a `Visitor` is that you hand a `task_at_hand` to a `ComplexDataModel` - an inheritance tree in this case - and let the model bring that task to where it needs to be executed - in my case on a single specific `Node`, if any. The rust-specific benefit? **No references needed** as the action all happens internally in the model, directly on the data!

In the below code, the 'task' is a function-pointer or closure called `visitor_func` handed to `Node::go_visit()`, that compares an id, and if not matched, recurses upward to a parent, if any. If matched, `visitor_func` is executed on that node.

```
//impl Node {...
pub fn go_visit<TReturnValue> (&self, 
         node_id: &str, 
         mut visitor_func: impl FnMut(&dyn Stuff) -> TReturnValue) -> Option<TReturnValue> 
{
    if self.id == node_id {
        Some(visitor_func(&self.stuff))
    } else {
        if self.parent.is_some() {
            let node = self.parent_scope.as_ref().unwrap();
            node.borrow().go_visit(id, visitor_func)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Note that:

1. In the original `Visitor` pattern, `go_visit()` is called `accept()` and `visitor_func` is often a class object, rather than a function pointer or closure.
2. I also specialized the `visitor_func` to take `node.stuff` as an argument, rather than the actual `node` as I don't care about the node itself.
3. By adding the generic `<TReturnValue>`, this `go_visit()` function can actually be used to return anything.

Usage:

```
let Some(result) = start_node.go_visit("some_id", |stuff| {
  stuff.calculate_a_result()
}) else {...};
//or simply test if a node exists:
if let Some(_) = start_node.go_visit("some_id", |stuff| ()) {
  // it exists!
}
//or
let exists = start_node.go_visit("some_id", |stuff| ()).is_some();
let exists = start_node.go_visit("some_id", |stuff| true).unwrap_or(false);
```

The visitor pattern can also be considered an iterator over possibly non-linear data.
Which makes me realize that the `go_visit()` function is very similar to `iter().find_map()`.